# Downloading Anaconda in ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to download and install anaconda in my ec2 instance(ubuntu). I have set the security group inbound rule to TCP (port 8888) and ssh (port 22) with MY IP as source for both. My outbound rule is set to All Traffic and destination as MY IP. I can successfully connect to the instance from terminal. But when I try to download anaconda I am getting error as 'Connection timed out and network not reachable'. Whats causing this and how to resolve?
[image]

Comment: Does the subnet you're using have any NACLs denying the ephemeral ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally recommended to leave the **Outbound security group** configured to allow All Traffic to **Anywhere** (`0.0.0.0/0`).

This gives the software and operating system permission to access anything on the Internet. In general, you can 'trust' the software running on your own computer and instances.

Security Groups are **statement**, meaning that if a connection is permitted, the **return traffic is also permitted**. This means that you can restrict the Inbound traffic so that it only comes from your IP address, but the instance can receive responses when using the Outbound rules to access the Internet.

To summarise:

- Set inbound as restrictive as possible (eg only allow your IP address to access)
- Set outbound to allow all traffic to Anywhere (unless you have a particular reason to restrict it)

Then you'll be able to download software.